# Image not getting displayed in exported Excel sheet

Tags: java, export-to-excel, nattable

I am exporting an Excel sheet using NatTable (Eclipse Nebula). It contains an image in the header layer and some text in the header as well as body. Here is the code for configuration:

```
ImagePainter bgImagePainter = new ImagePainter(getImg());       
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER, bgImagePainter, DisplayMode.NORMAL, HeaderLayout.overImg);
        configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellStyle, DisplayMode.NORMAL, HeaderLayout.overImg);
```

Also, I use `ExcelExporter` to export the data to an Excel Workbook.

I don't know where the error could be, because the text in all other columns is displayed perfectly. If you need to look at any other code snippet, I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the what the "error" could be, since you are not telling what your issue is. But I suppose your question is why the image is not exported. And AFAIK the reason is that the NatTable exporter does not support exporting of images at the moment.

Comment: Dirk, I am not getting any error on console or anywhere else. Also, I am already using custom NatTable exporter and custom ExcelExporter already. Currently, I am trying to figure out what I could change in the exporters in order to display the images. Any pointers?

Comment: Unfortunately not since I don't know how to embed images in a generated Excel. And from a quick search it doesn't seem to be a trivial task.